# Make a Edittext with format controll

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want make a `Edittext`, It should have some `controll bar` abover as: **bold/italic/normal/underline, align** with **html** tag.

A input of **Question** in **Stack overfllow** is a example for my idea.

Please show me a open source or a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Richeditor** might be the thing you want.

[image]

get this nice library from [GitHub](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android)

refer [this](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor) one also.

Comment: Thank you very much , it's something I need